# Select Multiple cell in tableView and display the selected cell in another tableView Cell as a label?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I'm creating an app related to iOS default alarm. I'm selecting a multiple cell in tableView. If I click the back button the selected cells are displayed in tableViewCell as a label in another view. I'm Using story board. How to do this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
       thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       [myIndexArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
}
else
{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    for(int i=0; i<myIndexArray.count; i++)
    {
        if([[myIndexArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue]== indexPath.row)
        {
            [myIndexArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

[The sample image I want like this](http://postimage.org/gallery/94r3n42k/22e8ea67/)

I want something like a Repeat View and press back button the selected cells are displayed in Repeat tableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same in my app. I can help you...
`RepeatDayViewController`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (UITableViewCellAccessoryNone == cell.accessoryType ) 
   {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    NSNumber *dayNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
    [self.repeatDays addObject:dayNumber];
   }
  else
  {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    NSNumber *dayNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
    [self.repeatDays removeObject:dayNumber];

   }
}
```

I am passing `self.repeatDays` to `AddAlarmViewController`

In
`AddAlarmViewController`
I have an array like this

```
 _days = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"Sun",@"Mon",@"Tue",@"Wed",@"Thu",@"Fri",@"Sat",nil];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

         if ([self.repeatDays count]) 
            {
                NSMutableArray *repeatDays = [NSMutableArray array]; 

                for (NSNumber *dayNumber in self.repeatDays) 
                {

                    [repeatDays addObject:[_days objectAtIndex:[dayNumber integerValue]]];
                }
                NSString *repeatLabel = [repeatDays componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = repeatLabel;

            }
            else
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Never",nil);
            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks i will check it n get back to u

Comment: @Anil I tried alreay..I want sample for the alarm app.pls pass to me

Answer (score 0):

Where ever the user select a row save the action any ware such as `NSUserDefaults`

in the

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


 UITableViewCell*   testCell = [azanTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"testCell"]==YES) {
    testCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    testCell .textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0];
}

}
```

And so on...