# Alarm app clarification

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm creating an alarm app. How to do the alarm app as same in default iphone alarm?
I want to do the same as in the image. 
Please give me a suggestion I'm new to iOS.

[SampleImage](http://postimage.org/gallery/bu6b7reg/d065dc97/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975401/select-multiple-cell-in-tableview-and-display-the-selected-cell-in-another-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are called `Table Views` and you can find how to work with them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)
Then you need to learn how to work with `Custom Table View Cells` you can find it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 0):

UI is easy and you can find some tutorials for it on [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) site
The only most important thing that you need to know about is audio sessions. Please check the [audio session programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
Audio session is important because you need to manage your alarm when app is in background/some other sound is playing like cases.